# aws apigateway not returning expected preflight headers, CORS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm troubleshooting a CORS issue and am currently analyzing the preflight headers.

I'm using an "HTTP" API in aws apigateway (different from what apigateway calls a "REST" api) to connect to a lambda function using the "lambda function" apigateway integration type.

It seems that no matter what I set in the CORS menu for HTTP apis, the preflight Response just doesn't have the headers I think I've enabled.

[image]

In the image below from devtools network tab, it's clear that apigateway is responding (hence the `apigw-requestid`). However, I would expect the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to be returned too. No such luck.

[image]

My $default stage is set to autodeploy.

I have a proper route and integration attached to the lambda, along with the proper http verb (POST in my case).

There's no authorization set.

I've tried returning the proper headers in my lambda itself, but as the aws documentation says, apigateway ignores them and writes its own stuff. (the lambda wasn't even contacted unless I added an OPTIONS route .. which seems unnecessary anyway)

Yes, there are many such questions here, but most direct you to apigateway "REST" apis, not "HTTP."

Comment: I found a workaround. Disable any CORS settings on the apigateway, set up an OPTIONS route in addition to my POST route. Then just handled all the headers inside the lambda itself. 

Why the CORS menu inside apigateway doesn't actually offer the headers you choose in its menus (yet still removes CORS headers from your lambda return) is still a mystery, but I'm sick of searching.

Comment: I have also solved the problem with separate OPTIONS route. For the fellow developers out there, don't use cors settings on HTTP API.

Comment: Wow, I've ran into the same issue https://repost.aws/questions/QUpGUTSs0cTaSjcxxtmCAxZQ/api-gateway-cors-error. I'm pretty frustrated about this one. I would like understand why CORS in API Gateway doesn't work for HTTP gateways with Lambda integrations. In any case, does this mean for each of my routes I have to setup a `OPTIONS` route? @StayCool @hahuaz

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem. I was using Axios and a GET request was working fine, but a PUT request was giving me a CORS error. I had configured CORS in the API Gateway exactly the same as you. Postman was working fine for PUT and GET.

I added the below to my lambda headers and added a route in API Gateway.

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, GET, PUT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
  };
```

Note that `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` could not be a * for Safari as it's not supported: [Access Control Allow Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods).