# API Gateway CORS 204 error with CORS enabled in API Gateway and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in lambda header

Tags: javascript, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway (HTTP) > Lambda > DynamoDB set up. I can successfully do a PUT and GET request through Postman but I am receiving a CORS error when I try and do a PUT request through my browser. I can successfully do a GET request through the browser.

A Post request through the browser returns

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/items' from origin 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have enabled CORS on the API Gateway. Automatic redeploy is on. I have also redeployed manually just in case.

[image]

I have also added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' to the headers in the lambda response. I have tried the lambda with and without these responses as I understand API Gateway should resolve the pre-flight request. Both ways still return a CORS 204 error.

[image]

```
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,PUT,GET'
  };

  try {
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "GET /items":
        // database call
      case "PUT /items":
        // databse put
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

I believe I should be seeing my headers in Postman, but I am not. I know the API Gateway is updating because if I remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the API Gateway Console, my GET request also fails due to CORS.

[image]

Comment: Try redeploying your API gateway

Comment: Auto redeploy is on. I have also manually redeployed just in case. It didn’t resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: [aws apigateway not returning expected preflight headers, CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69067390/aws-apigateway-not-returning-expected-preflight-headers-cors/73675085#73675085)

The solution was to not use API Gateway for CORS since it was simply not working. I had to add an OPTIONS route and return the desired headers.

Frustrating [since AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html) say the following.

`If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway automatically sends a response to preflight OPTIONS requests, even if there isn't an OPTIONS route configured for your API. For a CORS request, API Gateway adds the configured CORS headers to the response from an integration.`